# Application of spectral methods to numerically solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-transform

Consider a simple differential equation such as
$$
iU_t +U_{xx} = 0
$$
To solve using a spectral method I would do a Fourier transform and obtain
$$
i\hat{U_t} - k^2 \hat{U} = 0
$$
Where the hat refers to transformed quantities, and $k$ is from the spatial Fourier transform.
To apply the numerical solving, I would take time steps $\Delta t$ along the time axis and write
$$
\hat{U}^{n+1} = \hat{U^n} - ik^2 \Delta t \hat{U^n}
$$
and here the superscript denotes the time step, so $U$ at the next time step is now written as a function of the previous time step. Iterating over this gives an approximation to the solution on the desired time interval. Then I can take the inverse transform and it is done.

My question is how to apply such a theory. I can have an initial condition vector, at $t=0$, call it $U_0$. It needs to give a value to each point on the mesh along the $x$ interval in which I am interested. Then all things on the RHS are known, and the transforms are the fast Fourier transforms, done discretely. I never used the discrete transform before, it looks like this:
$$
X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n e^{-i2\pi kn /N}
$$
(from wikipedia).

So all the vectors are now indexed by $k$, but that seems strange, putting this into the numerical equation will mean each vector element is multiplied by its index? So in my equation I should have an element-wise multiplication of a vector $\textbf{k}_i = i^2$ with the vector $\hat{U}$

Comment: That's right; your forward Euler implementation should look like $\hat{U}^{n+1}_k=(1-i k^2 \Delta t) \hat{U}^n_k$. This assumes of course that the DFT is doing what you want it to do with regard to the spatial derivative, which I think is true but I would need to check it.

Comment: Ok, seems odd to have index components multiplying things all of a sudden, I thought i must have been abusing notation. If you check and notice I am wrong, then I would be happy to hear. Thanks!

Comment: You should watch out to make sure that you have the right coefficient for the derivative based on the type of FT that you are using. There could be some missing factors of $2 \pi$ or such depending on that.